# ゲストアカウントから登録へのフローは分かりやすいか

Tags: 討議, アカウント

> 最初にゲストで質問させていただき、そのあと登録を行‌​ったらふたつできてしまい、なおかつ最初のアカウントにログインできない

[android - 携帯端末で測定した加速度情報を世界軸座標に変換するには - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/9248)

というコメントがありました。
私はゲストで投稿したことが無いので、その後にアカウントを作成するためのフローが分からないのですが、このように誤って別アカウントを作成してしまうことがありうるのであれば、良いフローとは言えないと思います。
なんらかの改善はできないでしょうか（案もないのですが…）。

（このユーザさんの個人的な単純ミスだろうとは思うのですが、今後同様の事例があると問題があるかもしれないな、と思ったので起案させて頂きました。）

Comment: 関連しそうなmeta.SEの投稿です: [“Post as guest” is a bad user experience and encourages low quality contributions. Get rid of it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243712/post-as-guest-is-a-bad-user-experience-and-encourages-low-quality-contribution)

Answer (score 4):

試しにゲスト投稿してみたところ、アカウント登録を促すUIはあるようでした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、初回の投稿時に届くメールにも登録リンクがあります。

> 最近、スタック・オーバーフロー についてご質問をいただきましたが、メールアドレスの確認が完了していません。
>
> 次のリンクをクリックし、メールアドレスを確認した上でパスワードを設定すると、ログインできるようになります。
>
> [パスワードの設定]

というところで、大きく分けると次のようになるかと。

- 投稿したすぐ後に登録してくれる人 → 上記フローで登録
- 登録前にゲストアカウントを失ってしまい、

  - アカウント復元フォームやパスワード設定を利用する人
  - 別のアカウントを登録してしまった人 → jmacさんか問い合わせフォーム経由でマージ
  - それでもゲスト投稿する人

とはいえ、ユーザー登録していない人がパスワード再設定フォーム（＝アカウント復元フォーム）に行くとも考えにくいですし、軽く試した限りでは同じメールアドレスで別のゲストアカウントとして投稿できてしまうようですし、現状の仕様で問題ないとは言い難いですね…。